# in R: function to produce a list of named numbers populated from a lookup table and ordered by another list

Tags: r, function, lapply, tidyr

I 'm looking for guidance to produce a function returning a list of named numbers `q.arg2`. The element `q.arg2` should have *n* items where *n* is the number of arguments in the the character vector `factors2`. For each name in the factor list, the function should lookup in the dataframe `dist2` the distribution associated with the name. If the distribution is "normal" the function should return the named number `list(mean=x, sd=y)` by looking up those values in `dist2`. If the distribution is e.g. weibull the function should calculate the `shape1` and `shape2` parameters for the weibull distribution from a separate data frame `k2` that contains observation for each variable in the list , `factors2`. It should then return the named number `list(shape=x, scale=y)`. Finally, the sort order of `q.arg2` should be set using based on the object `sort2`.

The code below produces the elements referenced although note that `q.arg2` is just for reference. I wish for the function produced to output `q.arg2` given all other provided elements as arguments.

```
#gen dist2
id<-c("a", "b", "c")
mean<-c(3, 1, 4)
sd<-c(2,7,8)
distribution<-c("weibull", "normal", "normal")
dist2<-rbind(id,mean, sd, distribution)
dist2<-as.data.frame(dist2)
dist2 <- cbind(Row.Names = rownames(dist2), dist2)
rownames(dist2) <- NULL
colnames(dist2) <- c("variable", "var1", "var2", "var3")

#gen factors2
factors <- c("var2", "var3")

#the format that q.arg2 ought to take
q.arg2<-list(list(mean=1,sd=2), list(mean=1,sd=2))

#gen data frame for calculating weibull distributions
k2<-data.frame(replicate(2,rnorm(mean=100, sd=2,300)))
colnames(k2)<-c("var1", "var2")

#fit weibull distribution
require(fitdistrplus)
fw <- fitdist(k2$var1, "weibull")

sort2<-"a,b"
```

Comment: Your `sort2` refers to an id "b" which doesn't exist in `id`.

Comment: Good catch, Alexis. I corrected `dist2$id` to correct the problem.